# Angular NgbModal beforeDismiss not working

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I would like to add a class to the pop up modal before it is closed and then wait for a while before closing it. Looking at the documentation it looks like I can archive this with `beforeDismiss` in the `NgbModalOptions` options; https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

But it does not work. Here is my open method;

```
  open(content) {
    const options : NgbModalOptions = {
      size: 'lg',
      windowClass: 'animated bounceInUp',
      beforeDismiss: () => {
        setTimeout(()=>{
          alert ('Hello!');
        },2000);
        return false;
      }
    };
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(content, options).result.then((result) => {
      //this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      //this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
    console.log (this.modalRef);
  }
```

I don't mind closing it from outside if that is possible. For example something like `this.modalRef.close` but this shows an error modalRef.close is not a function.

### Update

This is my HTML;

```
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Save As Site Product Settings</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    {{product.title}}
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="saveProductAs()">Save As Site Product</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

I have discovered that it does not work on just this `<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>` But works on the cross icon. How do I get it to work on `c('Close click')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `beforeDismiss` function is called before the modal is dismissed but not before the modal is closed (there is a difference between close and dismiss).

As you have the following in the modal template:

```
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
```

you would have to call `d()` rather than `c()` to hook into the `beforeDismiss` button when the "Close" button is pressed:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="d('Close click')">Close</button>
```

See [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZplhGZsCN8HXAL11jedG?p=preview) for a demo.

Comment: Thanks this was what I was looking for. Do you know how I can change I could change the windowClass out of the .open(). So outside while the modal is still open.

Comment: That's probably not a very good question after looking at the code. I will just access it through the DOM.